# For Each of the Following Conditions Find a Subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

I was just wondering if it would be possible for someone to take a look and see if these examples make sense:

1- a connected, countably infinite set

-None exists

2- a set $S$ whose interior is its closure

-The whole real line

3- a set $S$ such that $\mathbb{R}\setminus S$ is the boundary of $S$

-The set $\mathbb{Q}$ of rational numbers

4- a disconnected set whose boundary is a one-point set

-Unsure

5- an uncountable set equal to its boundary

-Is there a better example than $\mathbb{R}$, the real line?

Comment: The boundary of the rational numbers are the reals. Instead, and also for the disconnected set whose boundary is a singleton take $ℝ \setminus \{0\}$. And the boundary of the real line is empty.

Comment: For disconnected set whose boundary is a one point set, you can just take $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$.

Comment: The middle-thirds Cantor set is an uncountable set equal to its boundary. $\Bbb R$ is not, as K. Stm. already mentioned.

Comment: 5- $\mathbb{R}$ is not equal to its boundary.

Comment: Thanks to all of you, very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first two are fine, and for your next two, consider instead $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$.

Now, a set that is equal to its boundary will be closed and have empty interior. (Why?) Can you think of an uncountable set that is closed and has empty interior? Perhaps one named after one of the giants of set theory?